# Accessing an array of HTML input text boxes using jQuery or plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm looking to create a form which contains a dynamic number of input text boxes. I would like each text box to form part of an array (this would in theory make it easier for me to loop through them, especially as I won't know the number of text fields that will eventually exist). The HTML code would like something like:

```
<p>Field 1: <input type="text" name="field[1]" id="field[1]"></p>
<p>Field 2: <input type="text" name="field[2]" id="field[2]"></p>
<p>Field 3: <input type="text" name="field[3]" id="field[3]"></p>
<p>Field 4: <input type="text" name="field[4]" id="field[4]"></p>
<p>Field 5: <input type="text" name="field[5]" id="field[5]"></p>
```

This data would then be sent to a PHP script and would be represented as an array - or at least, that's the theory.

So my first question is, is this achievable using HTML? Are forms designed to work that way?

If the answer to that is "yes", how would I then go about accessing each of those using jQuery or failing that, plain old JavaScript?

I've attempted to achieve this using the following jQuery code:

```
someval = $('#field[1]').val();
```

and

```
someval = $('#field')[1].val();
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
someval = document.getElementById('related_link_url')[1].value;
```

But I've not had any luck.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I should note that from a Javascript point of view, I've had it working where the ID of each element is something like field_1, field_2 etc. However, I feel that if I can achieve it by placing each text box into an array, it would make for tidier and easier to manage code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `id` attribute cannot contains `[` or `]` character.

There is lots of ways to get jQuery/plain JavaScript references to these elements. You can use descendant selector:

```
<fieldset id="list-of-fields">
   <!-- your inputs here -->
</fieldset>

$("#list-of-fields input");
document.getElementById("list....").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

You can also use attribute selector:

```
$("input[name^=field]");
```

I'm not sure whether that's the only way but I think in plain JavaScript you'll have to fetch all `input` elements (`document.getElementsByTagName`) and then loop through array of these elements and check each element (whether it has `name` attribute which value starts with `field`).

Answer (score 8):

Give each element a class and access the group using jQuery:

```
<p>Field 1: <input type="text" name="field[1]" class="fields"></p> 
<p>Field 2: <input type="text" name="field[2]" class="fields"></p>
<!-- etc... -->
```

jQuery:

```
$("input.fields").each(function (index)
{
    // Your code here
});
```

This will run the anonymous function on each `input` element with a classname of "fields", with the `this` keyword pointing to the current element.  See http://api.jquery.com/each/ for more info.

Comment: That's interesting. So the name field can include []s but the ID can't. So at least from a PHP point of view, I'd still be able to treat the $_POST['field'] data as an array?

And using $("input[name=field[1]]").val() I can still access the value using jQuery. So the key is to use name and not depend on ID.

Comment: @greggannicott: Square brackets are permitted in name attributes but not in ID attributes.  I think the correct way to use it for PHP is just have `name="field[]"` for each and not `name="field[n]"` but I could be mistaken and both might work.