# Disable text-boxes generated dynamically on multiple rows, based on user's selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The system asks the user to identify the number of records they would like to enter, based on their selection (say 3), the system displays three text boxes.

```
    <?php for($i=1; $i<=$rows; $i++) { ?> // $i is 3 here
      <input type="text" name="company_name[]" id="cn[]"> 
      <input type="text" size="3"name="entertainment[]" id="en[]">
    <?php } ?>
```

So this will generate 3 rows, with the same text boxes. If the user enters a value in the 1st row for entertainment, the company name should get grayed out or vice versa. Similarly it should do the same for the 2nd and 3rd line as well - based on which text box they fill.

How do I do that via js/jquery?

P.S: I am not a good front-end developer, so I could use all the help I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: Also make sure to use unique id values or use class

Comment: @Parth This is exactly what I asked.

Comment: Please do some code by your self. If you found any problem then we can do help to solve that. Also update your question after try something with jquery.

Comment: When using jquery, you can isolate your selections using `$(this)`

Comment: @Rasclatt How can I reference the index of the input ID array if it's dynamic?

Comment: This code from @David Thomas does the trick, but since the names of the boxes are the same, it applies the action on all the text boxes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192091/accessing-an-array-of-html-input-text-boxes-using-jquery-or-plain-javascript

Comment: You should check code of @AndyE in from your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrap then into `<div>`.
Element Id should be unique, change it as following

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=$rows; $i++) { ?> // $i is 3 here
<div>
<input type="text" name="company_name[]" onchange="grayOther(this);" id="cn_<?php echo $i ?>"> 
<input type="text" size="3"name="entertainment[]" onchange="grayOther(this);" id="en_<?php echo $i ?>">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Then here is the js.

```
<script>
function grayOther(elem){
    elem = $(elem); // convert to jquery object

    if (elem.val().length == 0) {
        elem.siblings().prop('disabled',false);
    }else {
        if (elem.is("[name='company_name[]']")){
            elem.siblings("[name='entertainment[]']").prop('disabled',true);
        }else {
            elem.siblings("[name='company_name[]']").prop('disabled',true);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```